# A variance-preserving Boolean function

Tags: pr.probability, st.statistics, probability-distributions

Let a random variable $X$ be given with $P_X$ supported over $\mathcal{X}$. What are the necessary conditions for the existence of a boolean function $f:\mathcal{X}\to \{0,1\}$ such that $\mathsf{var}(f(X))=\mathsf{var}(X)$?

Comment: $\textrm{Var}(X)\le 1/4$ is a necessary condition.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on that? 
Any proof? or at least any reference?

Comment: $f(X)$ only takes the values $0,1$.

Comment: $f(X)$ makes no sense to me.